# How to load pkcs12 and convert it to char* with openssl?

Tags: c, openssl, pkcs#12

I want to use openssl to load and encode pkcs12 to base64. I do not need to parse it just to load it and then encode it to base64, so when i decode it and put the contents in to file I will again have pkcs12 structure.

```
char* loadPkcs12(const char* path) {

    FILE *fp;
    PKCS12 *p12;

    OpenSSL_add_all_algorithms();
    ERR_load_crypto_strings();
    if (!(fp = fopen(path, "rb"))) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error opening file %s\n", path);
        exit(1);
    }
    p12 = d2i_PKCS12_fp(fp, NULL);
    fclose(fp);
    if (!p12) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error reading PKCS#12 file\n");
        ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);
        exit(1);
    }
    //here I am trying to encode it
    BIO* bio;
    bio = BIO_new(BIO_s_mem());
    i2d_PKCS12_bio(bio, p12);
    BUF_MEM *bufferPtr;
    BIO_get_mem_ptr(bio, &bufferPtr);
    printf(toBase64(bufferPtr->data));

    PKCS12_free(p12);
    return 0;
}

char* toBase64(char* str) {
    BIO *bio, *b64;
    BUF_MEM *bufferPtr;

    b64 = BIO_new(BIO_f_base64());
    bio = BIO_new(BIO_s_mem());
    bio = BIO_push(b64, bio);

    BIO_set_flags(bio, BIO_FLAGS_BASE64_NO_NL); //Ignore newlines - write everything in one line
    BIO_write(bio, str, strlen(str));
    BIO_flush(bio);
    BIO_get_mem_ptr(bio, &bufferPtr);
    BIO_set_close(bio, BIO_NOCLOSE);
    BIO_free_all(bio);
    char* output;

    output = (*bufferPtr).data;
    return output;
}
```

I know that the encoding to Base64 is working, the problem in converting the PKCS12 to char*. My output is right now only about 60 chars long and it should be much more longer. Is there a way how to convert PKCS12 to char* buffer? 
Thanks for very suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My output is right now only about 60 chars long and it should be much more longer. Is there a way how to convert PKCS12 to char* buffer?

I believe `toBase64` needs both a pointer and a length in case there's any embedded NULLs:

```
BUF_MEM *bufferPtr = NULL;
BIO_get_mem_ptr(bio, &bufferPtr);

if(bufferPtr != NULL) {
    if(bufferPtr->data && bufferPtr->length > 0)
        printf(toBase64(bufferPtr->data, bufferPtr->length));
}
```

And:

```
char* toBase64(char* str, int length) {
    ...
}
```

Ideally, you would use a `unsigned char*` rather than a `char*` for the pointer; and `size_t` rather than an `int` for length. But that ship has already sailed.

Also, be sure there's a NULL terminator on the Base64 string. I don't recall if its added automatically.

---

Related, you can chain the BIOs together with `BIO_push`. See the man pages on [`BIO_push(3)`](https://www.openssl.org/docs/crypto/BIO_push.html).

Comment: Thanks! It worked and also thanks for the NULL terminator and BIO_push tips

Comment: Could you share your solution with us (those who are not that into c)?